# How does the CLR know the type of a boxed object?

Tags: c#, clr, type-conversion, boxing

When a value type is boxed, it is placed inside an **untyped** reference object.
So what causes the invalid cast exception here?

```
long l = 1;
object obj = (object)l;
double d = (double)obj;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not placed in an untyped object. For each value type, there's a boxed reference type in the CLR. So you'd have *something* like:

```
public class BoxedInt32 // Not the actual name
{
    private readonly int value;
    public BoxedInt32(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

That boxed type isn't directly accessible in C#, although it is in C++/CLI. Obviously that knows the original type. So in C# you have to have a compile-time type of `object` for the variable but that doesn't mean that's the actual type of the object.

See the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) or [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) for more details.

Comment: Intersting, thanks Jon. Wagner's Effective C# states: "Boxing places a value type in an untyped reference object". I'm pretty sure it also says something to the effect that boxed objects don't contain any type metadata, though I can't find that particular quote right now. It was when reading that book that the question occured to me.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: I wouldn't like to put words into Bill's mouth about exactly what he meant by that - but the box object most definitely *does* know its original type, including enums. (Box an enum value and then use ToString directly with no unboxing for proof of that :)

Comment: I believe a good demonstration is this. `long l = 40L; object o = (object)l; Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());` In this case, System.Int64 is printed to the screen. Even though `o` is an object, the underlying type is still a long.

Answer (score 6):

Jon Skeet's answer covers the why; as for the how to get around it, here's what you have to do:

```
long l = 1;
object obj = (object)l;
double d = (double)(long)obj;
```

The reason for the dual cast is this; when .NET unboxes the variable, it only knows how to unbox it into the type it was boxed from (`long` in your example.) Once you've unboxed it and you have a proper `long` primitive, you can then cast it to `double` or any other type castable from `long`.